# Date shifting by one day in Sparklyr?

Tags: r, hive, rstudio, sparklyr

I am working on a time series forecasting project on R. However I need to fetch my data from the tables located in Hadoop environment. I am using Sparklyr to reach these tables. But I realized a strange problem after finishing data transfer.

My date column shifts by one day and I see 27.03.2017's data in the row representing 26.03.2017.

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", 
                    spark_home = "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/",
                    config = conf)

invoke(hive_context(sc), "sql", "USE mydb")

data <- tbl(sc, 'mydata_raw')
data.df <- data.frame(data)
filter(data.df, date == "2018-05-05")


          date        unit 
         <date>       <int>                 
1        2018-05-04   1111
```

In my hive tables there is no such problem.

Comment: I don't know `Sparklyr` but first thing I would check is if the time zones differ.

Comment: I have checked that. My R session and  Hive nodes share same timezone. I am not sure if there is a problem related with time zone.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue when you use Apache Spark directly (let's say with Scala or Python API), or is it something that happens only in `sparklyr`? Additionally how did you create the table in Hive? Could your provide corresponding DDL statement and Spark-side schema?

Comment: I do not experience same problem when I used `pyspark`. It happens only in `sparklyr`. I transfer data to HDFS by Kylo, then create table in Hive. Do you mean the statement, I used to create the table in Hive. If so, this is the code     `CREATE TABLE mydb.mydata_raw
(
    date DATE,
    unit INT
              )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u003B'
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
location '/mypath/myfolder'
TBLPROPERTIES("orc.compress"="snappy");`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, but it is definitely not the expected behavior, so I recommend [visiting sparklyr bug tracker](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues) and creating an issue.  [This issue has been raised on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54875323/10938362), but never (AFAIK) seen outside sparklyr. To further assign the blame you can check `filter(data.df, date == "2018-05-05") %>% spark_dataframe() %>% invoke("show")` and then `spark_log(sc)` to see if native Spark output looks OK. If you decide to open an issue please drop by, and leave an edit / comment with the link.

Comment: Hi I created a issue in Sparklyr bug tracker, here is the link; https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/1954